# Batch Programming: Moving Files to Folders Based on Date Modified

Tags: batch-file

Thanks for visiting. My question: I receive daily files that are stored as .csv's, typically with the following format: DEVICE_DEVICENumber_DateID. I'd like to move these files into their respective monthly folders (ie 201401) based on the Date portion of the DateID. The DateID is written as the date first followed by a unique device ID (ex YYYYMMDDUNIQUEID - 2014010110).

If I create folders like the one mentioned above (i.e. 201401, 201402, 201403, etc.), is there a simple way to pull a portion of the string to match the folder that I want to direct the file to?

Thanks for your help!

Calbruin

Typical filename:

GO.YO_WTR_SOO5_PT_20140102110.csv

Comment: An example showing a few typical `.csv` names would be useful. Just edit them into your question using `edit`.

Comment: You got it. Here's a typical example:  GO.YO_WTR_SOO5_PT_20140102110.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=.\csvfiles"
SET "destdir=c:\destdir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.csv" ') DO (
 SET "csvname=%%~na"
 IF NOT "!csvname:*_=!"=="!csvname!" (
  CALL :finddate
  ECHO MD "%destdir%\!csvname!"
  ECHO MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\!csvname!\"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
:finddate
IF /i "%csvname:~-6%"=="_audit" SET "csvname=%csvname:~0,-6%"
IF "%csvname:*_=%"=="%csvname%" SET "csvname=%csvname:~0,6%"&GOTO :EOF 
SET "csvname=%csvname:*_=%"
GOTO finddate
```

When applied to a directory '.\csvfiles` with content

```
GO.YO-WTR-SOO5-PT-20140102110.csv
GO.YO_WTR_SOO5_PT_20140102110.csv
```

Produced output

```
MD "c:\destdir\201401"
MOVE ".\csvfiles\GO.YO_WTR_SOO5_PT_20140102110.csv" "c:\destdir\201401\"
```

The required commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. After you've verified that the commands are correct, change `ECHO MD` to `MD` to actually create the directories.  Append `2>nul` to suppress error messages (eg. when the directory already exists)
Change `ECHO MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

---

Amendment - adjustment for ..._audit.csv.

Comment: This works very well and the files are being moved. They are placed into the Destdir that I have assigned, within a folder that is being labeled as !CSVNAME!. It looks like this folder is being generated every time I run the program. Should the files be going into the predefined folders I've created?

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify 'predefined folders' - in the original problem posted above, I went ahead and created folders for each year and month wihtin this calendar year; my hope was that files would be sent to those predefined folders (ie 201401). However the creation of a folder for each year/month would also work - I'm just not sure which of the two your code is attempting to do.

Comment: The `MD` command will create the appropriate directory. Appending ` 2>nul` to the `MD` command line will suppress the error message generated if the directory already exists. In this way, the batch will work even if you forget to establish the directories for a new year - in fact, you  don't even need to consider setting up those directories and you can take it off of your list of things to do. The batch will take care of it for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. This works very well, exactly as you mentioned! I have one additional file that is executed from the device and is written as GO.YO_WTR_SOO5_PT_20140102110_Audit.csv. Note that this contains the word AUDIT. Can I adjust this code easily to accomodate this other file name?